# Node.js and Apache ... How do I share POST data between the two?

Tags: apache, node.js

say I have a Login form ->

```
<form action="$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]" method="POST">
 <input...>
 <input...>
</form>
```

When using PHP with Apache, I would get the POST data by this variable: `$_POST["example"]`

However, I want to use the same `$_POST["example"]` to verify a user on a Node.js server.

so the user doesn't need to type in a form TWICE.

How can I get the POST data from APACHE to Node.js server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` or one of those `HTTPClient` libraries out there to send `POST` data to your node application as well.
Alternatively you can write the `POST` data to your node process input stream.